# CMake: How to move binaries up one directory after build?

Tags: c++, cmake

so I have the following project layout:

```
- CMakeLists.txt
- include/
  - ...
- src/
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - binary1.cc
  - binary2.cc
  - ...
- third_party/
  - project1/
     - CMakeLists.txt
     - ...
- bin/
```

The CMakeLists.txt in the root directory basically contains the following statements:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(third_party/project1)
...
```

To build I do the following:

```
cd bin/
cmake ..
make
```

.. which will happily build everything, but it places `binary1` and `binary2` into `/bin/src` whereas I would prefer them to live in `/bin/` directly (for some compatibility reasons).

I tried the following, but cmake will not configure because " ../bin is already used to build a source directory. It cannot be used to build.":

```
add_subdirectory(src .)
```

Can someone provide hints?

Comment: You could maybe use [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) like adding `-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$PWD` to the cmake command. You could also use `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR)`

Comment: `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}) worked. Previously I had tried set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY .) but that didn't do it. Thanks.